# Can an Outlook js add-in receive push notifications from an external server using web sockets or similar?

Tags: javascript, websocket, outlook, outlook-addin, clientwebsocket

I'm trying to create a near real-time two way sync experience with my cloud based CRM and a user's Outlook Calendar. If the client makes a change in the cloud CRM, my cloud based server should push a notification to the Outlook Add-In to update the user's calendar to reflect the latest change. I've heard that Outlook js Add-Ins currently use IE11 (which supports web sockets,) as the html/js engine. Has anyone tried this? Or does Outlook explicitly prevent that?